# discord.errors.InvalidArgument: components must be a list of Component

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Делаю Discord бота с кнопками, но как только запускаю его - ругается на список с кнопками. Просьба помочь, т.к. обыскал почти **все**. Код снизу.

````py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dislash import InteractionClient
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
inter_client = InteractionClient(client)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('включено!')
    DiscordComponents(inter_client)

@inter_client.slash_command(description="Начать покупку.")
async def start(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Главное меню", description="Выберите категорию")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/604620332967657472/a_33fe6b55b52acb9402bc142ce45b934f.gif")
    buttons = [
Button(style = ButtonStyle.blue, label = ' Магазин'), 
Button(style = ButtonStyle.blue, label = ' Профиль'), 
Button(style = ButtonStyle.blue, label = ' Поддержка')
]
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed, components=buttons)
    
client.run("токен")```
````

Answer (score 0):

попробуй так, исправил тебе несколько ошибок

````html
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dislash import InteractionClient
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
inter_client = InteractionClient(client)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('включено!')
    DiscordComponents(inter_client)

@inter_client.slash_command(description="Начать покупку.")
async def start(ctx):
    await stx.send(
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Главное меню", description="Выберите категорию")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/604620332967657472/a_33fe6b55b52acb9402bc142ce45b934f.gif")
        components=[
            Button(style = ButtonStyle.blue, label = ' Магазин'),
            Button(style = ButtonStyle.blue, label = ' Профиль'),
            Button(style = ButtonStyle.blue, label = ' Поддержка')
        ]
    )

client.run("токен")```
````

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: чтобы мне жаловалось, какого фига мы указали embed и почему мы потом указываем функцию? нет уж, спасибо, раз копипастить - то правильно